# how can i use onchange from product field to one2many field of purchase order line odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Like i have one field in product.template with the field name squ_meter which i need to copy this value in custom field of purchase order line with same field name i.e squ_meter  and i want to apply onchange on purchase order line field

Any kind of help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Here's my code

class purchase_order_line(osv.osv):

```
_inherit = 'purchase.order.line'

_columns ={'squ_meter' : fields.float('Square Meter'),

    }
```

purchase_order_line.xml

```
<field name="name">purchase.order.inherit</field>
<field name="model">purchase.order</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">      
    <xpath expr="//page[@string='Products']//field[@name='order_line']//field[@name='product_qty']"  position="after">
        <field name="squ_meter"/>
    </xpath>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Related Fields**

Related field is useful when you want to keep the values of any relational fields except it's reference then it would be easier way to do it.

**[OLD API](http://openerp-server.readthedocs.org/en/latest/03_module_dev_02.html#relational-types)**

```
_columns ={
        'squ_meter': fields.related('product_id','squ_meter', type='float',    relation='product.product', string='Square Meter', readonly=True),
    }
```

**Where**:

- The first set of parameters are the chain of reference fields to
  follow, with the desired field at the end.
- type is the type of that desired field.
- Use relation if the desired field is still some kind of reference. relation is the table to look up that reference in.

**[NEW API](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#related-field)**

There is not anymore fields.related fields.

Instead you just set the name argument related to your model:

```
squ_meter = Fields.Float(string='Square Meter', related='product_id.squ_meter' , readonly=True)
```

**purchase_order_line.xml**

```
<field name="name">purchase.order.inherit</field>
<field name="model">purchase.order</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">      
    <xpath expr="//page[@string='Products']//field[@name='order_line']//field[@name='product_qty']"  position="after">
        <field name="squ_meter" readonly="1" />
    </xpath>
</field>
```